# Is a path integral over a region with a bottleneck still unitary?

Tags: path-integral, quantum-gravity, unitarity, volume

Consider the following hourglass-shaped region of spacetime:

[image: A region of spacetime whole boundary looks like a hyperboloid of 1 sheet.]

The red circular cross sections are the initial and final conditions, which can vary, while we fix a particular boundary condition on the blue walls of the region. If we solve a wave equation over a region that looks like this, then the dynamics should be reversible. The intuition would be that inside the bulk of the region the wave equation is reversible, and at the boundary the waves would simply bounce off, always resulting in a conservation of information.

Since the classical dynamics is reversible, I would expect the corresponding quantum dynamics to be reversible too. In other words, if we switch from solving a classical wave equation to evaluating a QFT path integral, we should get a unitary matrix that maps from the initial condition to the final condition. This seems a little counter-intuitive, since the entire amount of information at the beginning must pass through a narrow bottleneck, and then come out at the end with no loss. But if we consider that there's no upper limit to energy in QFT, it makes sense. Waves that are long at the start will be blueshifted as they bounce back and forth between the converging walls, so they will naturally be squeezed into a smaller size. So it makes sense that the bottleneck would be able to support a high information density.

However, we *should* worry about the physical size of the bottleneck when we're dealing with gravity. If the energy density gets too big at the bottleneck, then a black hole might form. To put it another way, the surface area of the boundary is small at the bottleneck, but large at the start and end of the region. I'm very much not an expert here, so I could be wrong, but I think there's a bound in quantum gravity saying that the amount of information that can flow through a surface is equal to the boundary area of that surface. Since the bottleneck has a much smaller boundary area, this should imply that the matrix we get out of the path integral can't be unitary, since the bottleneck is literally too small to pass all the information we're trying to put in.

What's the resolution to this paradox? Is the matrix we get out indeed not a unitary matrix, or (more likely) have I made an error somewhere in the reasoning above?

Comment: Possibly related (but definitely a different) question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261352/is-a-unitary-hamiltonian-tqft-the-same-as-a-unitary-axiomatic-tqft